# R calculation in time spans

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df on shared bicycles with 600k lines with information regarding 7 days with updates of data, more or less, every minute, where I need to calculate a probability in time spans. An example of the df:

```
Name NrBikes Data Time MaxBikes TotalDocks Probability
A 16 2020.10.01 01:00:00 x 26 y
B 16 2020.10.01 01:01:00 x 26 y
...
C 8 2020.10.01 02:00:00 x 26 y
...
D 14 2020.10.01 03:00:00 x 26 y
```

What I need is the values for x and y, where x refers to the maximum "NrBikes" between the time of the row and-1/+1 hour (for example, for the 05:00:00 row I need the "MaxBikes" for the time span between 04:00:00 and 06:00:00).

After that, the value of y is just dividing x (MaxBikes) by the column "Total Docks".

I am grouping by data and name of the dock:

```
analiseGiras <- analiseGiras %>%   group_by(add_data, desigcomercial) %>% ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are the rows evenly spaced in time (each row advances 1 second like in your example), or is it variable (some rows advance 1 second, some 15 minutes, etc.)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. They change a bit, between 1min 2s and 1min 13s from what I could understand. For every time event I have a max of 85 rows (corresponding to 85 different shared bike docks), i.e: there are 85 rows for the time 14:01:02 then 83 rows for the time 14:02:10 then 84 rows for the time 14:03:19, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've found a way to deal with this problem of calculating the cumsum in time intervals in the following way. Note that in this case I calculated in 30 minute time intervals.

```
i=as.POSIXct("2020-10-15 03:00:00")
j=i+1800
a=1
listofdfs <- list()

i < as.POSIXct("2020-10-15 23:59:59")

while (a <= 42){
    listofdfs[[a]] <- analiseGiras %>%
    filter(time > i & time < j) %>%
    group_by(add_data, desigcomercial) %>%
    mutate(retiradas30 = cumsum(ifelse(volume>0,volume,0)),
           devolvidas30 = cumsum(ifelse(volume<0,volume,0)))
   a=a+1
   i=i+1800
   j=j+1800
   print(a)
   print(i)
   print(Sys.time())    }

df <- ldply(listofdfs, data.frame)

analiseGirasNew <- df
```

- analiseGiras is the main dataframe.
- I've created a while loop that iterates over every  minute interval between 03:00:00 up until 24:00:00, calculating the cumsum of the variables I needed, grouped the way I needed and writing it to a list. Aftewars I've compiled the list into a dataframe and wrote it as the new main dataframe.